# How to override the partial_update in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Overriding partial_update is not working for me. I want to partial_update based on status. If an order is 'Out for Delivery' or 'Delivered', then user is not able to change any fields, but in my case, he is able to.
Below is the code of mine. How should I correct this?

**views.py**

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch']
    serializer_class = PizzaOrderSerializer)
    queryset = PizzaOrder.objects.all()

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order = self.get_object()
        data = request.data
        if order.status == 'Open' or 'Accepted' or 'Preparing':
            order.flavours = data.get('flavours', order.flavours)
            order.number = data.get('number', order.number)
            order.size = data.get('size', order.size)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
        order.save()
        serializer = PizzaOrderSerializer(order, partial=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**models.py**

```
STATUS_CHOICE = (
    ('Open', 'Open'),
    ('Accepted', 'Accepted'),
    ('Preparing', 'Preparing'),
    ('Out for Delivery', 'Out for Delivery'),
    ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
)


class PizzaOrder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False)
    flavours = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=FLAVOURS_CHOICE)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SIZE_CHOICE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, default='Open')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PizzaOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PizzaOrder
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'flavours', 'number', 'size', 'customer_name', 'customer_address', 'ordered_time', 'status',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'id': {'read_only': True},
            'name': {'read_only': False},
            'flavours': {'read_only': False},
            'number': {'read_only': False},
            'size': {'read_only': False},
            'customer_name': {'read_only': False},
            'customer_address': {'read_only': False},
            'ordered_time': {'read_only': True},
            'status': {'read_only': True}
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you have a not correct `if statement` in `class CustomerViewSet`line 9.
Maybe better as below:

```
if order.status in ('Open', 'Accepted', 'Preparing'):
    pass
```

In your case on that statement, if order.status not "Open" then statement always will return "Accepted", so it means `True`.